# How to separate 3D .img file from 4D nii file?

Tags: python, matlab

I have 4D .nii fMRI data file. I want to separate header and image file (.img) and save them separately. I googled it but could not get a working code for this. Please share your knowledge if you have any codes available to you.

Comment: You might want to link to some documentation of the structure of these `.nii` files and mention existing software that works with them. This questions is too broad and requires much more details to be useful. If during your search you came across some code which you didn't manage to get working, you should **absolutely** mention this! A quick search gave me both a python and a MATLAB [tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/niftilib/files/) - is this not what you need?

Comment: @Dev-iL 4D .nii fMRI means 3D image plus 1D deader files. Btw I solved this issue not expecting any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. I am posting my solution here. 4D data means 3D image data plus 1 D header data. First I extracted all the image slices from 4D files. Then converted extracted images into .mat files. This was the requirement of my code.